# vector <double> to double error in c++ code

Tags: c++, random, vector

I am trying to return a value that is in a vector that is returned on a weighted random distribution(i.e. if the vector had 1,2,3 it would give a 1/6 chance of 1 and 2/6 chance of 2 and a 3/6 chance of 3). I am getting compile time errors of

```
Protein.cpp:809:54: error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >’ to ‘double’ in assignment
Protein.cpp:814:24: error: could not convert ‘((Protein*)this)->Protein::fitness1.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<double, std::allocator<double> >((std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::size_type)index)’ from ‘double’ to ‘std::vector<double>’
```

when I compile the code and have had very little luck trying to fix it. If anyone could take a look at the function and help me out, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks again for your time before hand!

function

```
vector<double> Protein::Init_Seq_Recursive(State& s, int d)
{
    vector<float> sequence;
    double index;
    float initial;
    int i =0;
    for (i; i < k; i++)
    {
        s[d] = i;
        if (d == (L - 1))
        {
            int ind = Index(s);


            Ef[ind] = GetEf(s);
            Eb1[ind] = GetEb1(s);
            Eb2[ind] = GetEb2(s);
            double zf = exp(beta_f*Ef[ind]);
            double zb1 = exp(beta_b*Eb1[ind]);
            double zb2 = exp(beta_b*Eb2[ind]);


            fitness1[ind] = (1. + f_ub*zb1 + f_ub*f_uf*zf*zb1)/( 1. + zb1 + zf*zb1 );
            fitness2[ind] = (1. + f_ub*zb2 + f_ub*f_uf*zf*zb2)/( 1. + zb2 + zf*zb2 );



        }       
        else
            Init_Fitness_Recursive(s, d + 1);
    }
    if(i==k-1){
        vector<float> weights;
        float running_total = 0;


        for(int y = 0; y<pow(k,L); y++){
            running_total = running_total+fitness1[y];
            weights.push_back(running_total);


        }
        double rnd = (static_cast <double> (rand()) / static_cast <double> (RAND_MAX))*running_total;
        for(int y = 0; y<fitness1.size(); y++){
            if(rnd<weights[y]){
            index = find(fitness1.begin(), fitness1.end(), rnd);
            }       
        }

    }
    return(fitness1[index]);

}
```

Comment: What is the data type of `fitness1`?

Comment: Seems like you are returing a single double where you are supposed to return a vector of doubles.

Comment: `fitness1[index]` is probably not a `vector<double>`, which the function is supposed to return.

Comment: fitness1 is a double vector

Comment: But not a vector of double vectors. Since you return fitness1[index]. That has to be a vector of doubles not just a double.

Comment: If you have a trouble with returning values you don't need to post 30+ lines of arbitrary code. It would be better to cut out everything unnecessary and post a whole example that reproduces the error. And what on earth made you use a `double` for array indexing?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::find` doesn't return an index. It returns an iterator pointing at the found element. To get the `index`, you need compute the distance between the `begin` iterator and the one you found. Like this:

```
vector<double>::iterator found = find(fitness1.begin(), fitness1.end(), rnd);
index = distance(fitness1.begin(), found);
```

It is pretty suspect that you would use a `double` for an index into a container though.

Additionally, your `return(fitness1[index]);` is trying to return a single `double`, but your return type is `vector<double>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
index = find(fitness1.begin(), fitness1.end(), rnd);
```

The return value of `find` is an iterator. You need to dereference it to get a `double` (that is the type of `index`):

```
index = *find(fitness1.begin(), fitness1.end(), rnd);
//      ^
```

Secondly, you're trying to return a `double` from a function that's declared to return a `vector<double>`:

```
return( fitness1[index] );
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I thought the name `index` suggested he wanted an index to the found element, while you thought `double` suggested he wanted the element itself. Interesting.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Your guess is as good as mine (and probably better, because I didn't delve in the logic at all).